# VS2019 copy project within solution to use as starting point for new project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

Hi I have a VS2019 solution that contains multiple projects, some are class libraries and some are commandline apps

I want to start a new commandline app but would like to base it on an existing app in the solution.

Is there any easy way to do this?
Or do I just have to start the new project and then labouriously copy all the references, progrma.cs etc etc...

If thats the case then fine.. I am just wondering if I am missing a trick here, maybe this is something people do a lot?

Thanks

Comment: Copy the folder for the project in the file system and then add the copy via "add existing project". There might be some renaming needed before but if you haven't got wild somewhere in using absolute pathes to something where you shouldn't it will work.

Comment: I have shown the specific operation process below, you can check it out. If you accept it and it works, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy Project:

[image]
[image]

2. Add Existing Project:

[image]

[image]

[image]

3. Rename the project otherwise an error will be reported.

[image]

After renameing:

[image]

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?